# Silverlight: Image Source with no file extension doesn`t display

Tags: image, silverlight-4.0

In my Silverlight project, images for which the source URI does not contain the file extension don`t display, although the documentation says it should.

I set the image source like so:

```
imgCompanyLogo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, "/Files/" + logoName));
```

Now, if "logoName" contains the file extension (like ".png" for example), the image is displayed fine, but it simply doesn't if the file is stored without an extension.

This seems to contradict the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602473%28VS.95%29.aspx) which states:

"The format-specific filename extensions such as .png are not necessarily required to be in the URI naming, but if the retrieved file is not determined to be a valid image format, a runtime exception is thrown."

I'm not getting any runtime exception either.
Is this a known issue or am I missing something simple?

Thanks!

PS: Just a little twist, the images display fine while debugging, not when the system is deployed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some test and the problem seems to be due to the response from the server.

If you try using .png within your project with a Build Action sets to Resource, both images will load regardless the extension.

Now if you try with images hosted on a server, it won't have the same behavior. Actually, if you try to browse the link to an image without extension directly in your browser, it will result in something else. On Chrome it will download the file, and on IE it will display the result as plain text.

That's because of the MIME type. A png should be returned with the type image\png.

There is a trick with .htaccess to set up the MIME-type but you need to have to specify for which extension. It works like this:

> AddType image\png yourExtension [Extension2] [Extension3] ..

And if you want to see if why the image didn't load on your Image control, you can add an eventhandler to the ImageFailed event:

```
<Image Source="..." ImageFailed="Image_ImageFailed" />
```

But the error message that you will see is not really helpful:

ErrorException = {System.Exception: AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR}

Comment: Interesting, did not know about the .htaccess trick, I'm going to play with that. I had noticed the basic browsing behaviour, but given the documentation, I was hoping they had already implemented it behind the scenes for images. Cheers!